# Maintaining precision when parsing/reading Json nodes for a D3 graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a Json file representing a graph with nodes and links. The node id's are integers but quite large. 
Eg. Json:

```
"directed": false, 
"graph": {}, 
"nodes": [
    {
        "parity": 0, 
        "degree": 17, 
        "fraud_id": 1, 
        "component": -9202453918824477682, 
        "community": 0, 
        "fraudind": 1, 
        "betweenness": 0.0, 
        "id": 589139887331672165
    }, 
    {
        "parity": 0, 
        "degree": 21, 
        "fraud_id": 1, 
        "component": -9202453918824477682, 
        "community": 1, 
        "fraudind": 1, 
        "betweenness": 0.17316017316017315, 
        "id": 6847927546904557618
    },
```

When I try to parse the data using d3.json() the datum does not maintain the precision. So the id for the above node becomes `589139887331672000` removing the last three digits. The following eg. illustrates this:

```
function myFunc(data) {
        console.log(data);
}
d3.json(strUser, function (error, graph) {
  myFunc(graph);
  force1.nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

   var link = svg_g1.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", function (d) {
      return color2(d.edge_property);
    })
   var node = svg_g1.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 5)  // radius
    .style("fill", function (d) {
      return color(d.fraudind);
    })
    .attr("id", function (d) {
      return "c" + d.id;
    })
    .call(force1.drag)
}
```

In the above the `"c"+d.id` is not giving the exact ID from the json but the rounded number. How can I ensure the data being read by d3.json maintains the precision or is read as a string instead of an integer?

Comment: Can you place the IDs in quotes?  JavaScript cannot handle numbers less than -9,007,199,254,740,991 or larger than 9,007,199,254,740,991.

Comment: I am dumping out the json from the networkX library. Though I could change the nodes from numbers to String I still am wondering if it could be done within JS itself

Comment: @RickHitchcock Thanks it's working with nodes as strings